# Bizarre IE CSS Problem

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, jquery-corner

So my problem has to do with a Sticky footer that works, but a rounded corner script pushes the footer up a bit in IE7. (example: [Games Page](http://callynandmike.com/games/games.php)) If you load the page in IE7, the footer is in the wrong place, but if you do the following:
1. Open a new tab
2. Go to google.ca in the new tab (or do something)
3. Close the tab
The footer problem is fixed. I cannot wrap my head around why this is.

Comment: i can't see the error you're referring to.

Comment: ... or any rounded corners...

Comment: @nickf - I think he's referring to a placehloder div which doesn't actually have rounded corners in it yet, question is a tad poorly-phrased. I can re-produce error here in IE7, it's a strange one alright.

Answer (score 1):

After writing this I found this article on stack overflow: [IE CSS Bug - How do I maintain a position:absolute when dynamic javascript content on the page changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837/ie-css-bug-how-do-i-maintain-a-positionabsolute-when-dynamic-javascript-content) And this seems to address the same problem.